# FP number's exponent field is not what I expected, why?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I've been stumped on this one for days. I've written this program from a book called Write Great Code Volume 1 Understanding the Machine Chapter four.

The project is to do Floating Point operations in C++. I plan to implement the other operations in C++ on my own; the book uses HLA (High Level Assembly) in the project for other operations like multiplication and division.

I wanted to display the exponent and other field values after they've been extracted from the FP number; for debugging. Yet I have a problem: when I look at these values in memory they are not what I think they should be. Key words: what I think. I believe I understand the IEEE FP format; its fairly simple and I understand all I've read so far in the book.

The big problem is why the Rexponent variable seems to be almost unpredictable; in this example with the given values its 5. Why is that? By my guess it should be two. Two because the decimal point is two digits right of the implied one.

I've commented the actual values that are produced in the program in to the code so you don't have to run the program to get a sense of whats happening (at least in the important parts).
It is unfinished at this point. The entire project has not been created on my computer yet.

Here is the code (quoted from the file which I copied from the book and then modified):

```
#include<iostream>

typedef long unsigned real; //typedef our long unsigned ints in to the label "real" so we don't confuse it with other datatypes. 
using namespace std; //Just so I don't have to type out std::cout any more!

#define asreal(x) (*((float *) &x)) //Cast the address of X as a float pointer as a pointer. So we don't let the compiler truncate our FP values when being converted.

inline int extractExponent(real from) {
    return ((from >> 23) & 0xFF) - 127; //Shift right 23 bits; & with eight ones (0xFF == 1111_1111 ) and make bias with the value by subtracting all ones from it.
}


void fpadd ( real left, real right, real *dest) {
    //Left operand field containers
    long unsigned int Lexponent = 0;
    long unsigned     Lmantissa = 0;
    int               Lsign = 0;
    //RIGHT operand field containers
    long unsigned int Rexponent = 0;
    long unsigned     Rmantissa = 0;
    int               Rsign = 0;
    //Resulting operand field containers
    long int                Dexponent = 0;
    long unsigned   Dmantissa = 0;
    int             Dsign = 0;

    std::cout << "Size of datatype: long unsigned int is: " << sizeof(long unsigned int); //For debugging
    //Properly initialize the above variable's:
    //Left
    Lexponent = extractExponent(left); //Zero. This value is NOT a flat zero when displayed because we subtract 127 from the exponent after extracting it! //Value is: 0xffffff81
    Lmantissa = extractMantissa (left); //Zero. We don't do anything to this number except add a whole number one to it. //Value is: 0x00000000

    Lsign = extractSign(left); //Simple.
    //Right
    **Rexponent = extractExponent(right); //Value is: 0x00000005 <-- why???**
    Rmantissa = extractMantissa (right);
    Rsign = extractSign(right);



}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    real a, b, c;

    asreal(a) = -0.0;
    asreal(b) = 45.67;

    fpadd(a,b, &c);

    printf("Sum of A and B is: %f", c);
    std::cin >> a;
    return 0;
}
```

Help would be much appreciated; I'm several days in to this project and very frustrated!

Comment: Your question ("why 5?") is burried in the middle of needlessly long code, please improve your question. Why do you believe the exponent shouldn't be 5? (by the way, the cast to float breaks strict aliasing, but that's for another question).

Comment: I just edited it; is this much better?

Comment: Also I did not modify the #Define code; that's straight from the book. The book called it a "sneaky" way to treat the float as a float without converting it to anything else. What it means by this I don't know. I'm just a hobbyist programmer, everything I know was self taught or from a high school class.

Comment: Floating point works in binary, for 45.xx thus 2^5<x<2^6. Therefore it is 5. I think the code is correct,

Comment: However, to be frank, there exists a decimal floating point standard in the last std revision but this is out of place for your question.

Comment: Yes I know that Garp, the book was written in 2004 and the latest IEEE standard was implemented in 2008. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in this example with the given values its 5. Why is that?

The floating point number 45.67 is internally represented as

```
2^5 * 1.0110110101011100001010001111010111000010100011110110
```

which actually represents the number

```
45.6700000000000017053025658242404460906982421875
```

This is as close as you can get to 45.67 inside `float`.

If all you are interested in is the exponent of a number, simply compute its base 2 logarithm and round down. Since 45.67 is between 32 (2^5) and 64 (2^6), the exponent is 5.

Comment: The reason I said this was the answer is because it reminded me of what the book said about how the computer represents small numbers. That was exactly as you said, and though I do know what a logarithm is and how to use it I had forgotten how to get the decimal value of a log. Maybe if you had discussed why you were rounding I would have been less confused. I know now that's because the datatype does not hold FP exponents, it can only hold an integer. Alls well though; thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

Computers use binary representation for all numbers. Hence, the exponent is for base two, not base ten. int(log2(45.67)) = 5.